# Bitmap OutMemoryOfException in android

Tags: android, azure, gridview, bitmap, android-asynctask

I try to load images from blob azure to gridview in android. In doInBackground i have this code`

```
ArrayList<Bitmap> userBitmaps=new ArrayList<>();
URL urlConnection = new URL(blob.getUri().toString());
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlConnection.openConnection();
connection.setDoInput(true);
connection.connect();
Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL(blob.getUri().toString()).getContent());
userBitmaps.add(bitmap);`
```

When I open the page with this gridview the first time all is ok, but the second time I have this error

```
    E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1                                                                                   java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
                             at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:352)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:219)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:239)
at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1080)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:573)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)

Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:623)
at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:696)
at com.example.gaya.searchpeople.UsersInfoActivity$NetworkConnector.doInBackground(UsersInfoActivity.java:151)
at com.example.gaya.searchpeople.UsersInfoActivity$NetworkConnector.doInBackground(UsersInfoActivity.java:119)
at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:234)`
```

Please, help to solve my problem, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

bitmap occupy memory so much.suggest use [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco),[Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide),or [picasso](https://github.com/square/picasso) to download the picture.these image-loading librays can handle the bitmap conveniently.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest not handling Bitmaps and memory yourself.

Instead use a library like [Glide](https://github.com/bumptech/glide) to load bitmaps into `ImageView`s

Answer (score 0):

These `Bitmap` objects generated by `BitmapFactory`, which memories can not recycled by Android garbage collection mechanism because the generation of Bitmap objects are realized by calling the JNI method if check the `BitmapFactory` sourcecode can be seen.

The Android developer website had shown how to [Managing Bitmap Memory](https://developer.android.com/topic/performance/graphics/manage-memory.html). And there is a [blog](http://www.programering.com/a/MTMycDNwATg.html) which introduces 4 ways for resolving the `OutOfMemory` issue of `Bitmap` to know how to do the memory optimization for `Bitmap`.